# Liferay installation on IBM BlueMix

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, liferay, ibm-cloud

I am trying to get `Liferay 6.2 CE GA6` running on `IBM BlueMix`. Therefore I downloaded the general package from Liferay and did the following changes:

I added:

```
 - /WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
 - /WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
```

The content of `portal-ext.properties` is as below:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/ad_7fc926ce99ebab9?usermyUser&password=myPassword
jdbc.default.username=myUser
jdbc.default.password=myPassword
```

Afterwards I set up compute --> tomcat and attached a ClearDB MySQL Database.

I cannot boot up the package. I executed the following command from the extracted folder of Liferay (incl. my changes):

```
cf push myApp
```

I receive the following error:

```
2016-07-19T00:53:22.85+0200 [App/0]      ERR
2016-07-19T00:53:22.91+0200 [DEA/195]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start
accepting connections
2016-07-19T00:53:22.93+0200 [API/9]      OUT App instance exited with guid f2b42
06e-5683-4f29-89b3-a5846bc877cd payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"f2b4206e-5683-4f29-89b3-a5846bc877cd", "version"=>"02efa335-eb35-4cb1-a630-3501
250401f1", "instance"=>"1844abae7f05428fb59fa5d5e8bfdc43", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>148, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connection
s within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1468882402}
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't look like enough information to me. Did you also install the Liferay dependencies that go onto the global (tomcat) classpath?

Comment: When you say `I downloaded the general package from Liferay`, what are you talking about ? Liferay dependecies ? Liferay portal ?

Comment: I installed the LifeRay WAR (https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.2.5%20GA6/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6-20160112152609836.war/download) and moved the mysql connector into /WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. Further I created /WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties with the configuration available in the question. How may I deploy the dependencies via IBM BlueMix? I assume that thee following JARs are required: jta.jar and mail.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat dependencies can be placed within the *.war and further containers can be referenced within the portal-ext.properties.

This way the *.war can be adjusted.